# Remove Visualforce Page from Home Page Sidebar

Tags: visualforce, visualforce-component, configuration, home-page-component, home-page-layout

I've a Salesforce application in which on my Home Tab there is one page displayed in the Sidebar. I wanted to remove that page from the sidebar.

I tried searching it in my **Home Page Layouts** and **Home Page Components** but that didn't help. Below is the screenshot of my home page:

[image]

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: SoftPhone layouts with errors in VF page inside? Can you deactivate that and see if there's an error?

Comment: What is SoftPhone layouts and how to see it's error?

Comment: what may be shown to you at the right -- is misconfigured calling center. Go to setup -> Customize -> Call Center -> Call Centers, and check if  there are any. Disable them from your user